# Pager for multivalued node field

Tags: 7, entities, javascript

There is a plenty of plugins for building all kinds of sliders and carousels with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).

But frequently I find myself in a situation, when I need to make some kind of slider not for a whole node but only for one particular field with multiple values. Of course, I can attach a view using the [EVA](http://drupal.org/project/eva) module and use it to output just one field of current node.

But is it a recommended way? Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CCK Pager](http://drupal.org/project/cck_pager) module.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work on D7